# android app stuck on white screen and sometimes crashes after a while

Tags: java, android

I have an android which works fine for most of the time but it fails to go beyond the white screen sometimes and the logcat only prints one message in loop "V/FA: onActivityCreated" that's it and nothing else and i could only make it work by uninstalling and reinstalling again.

So, i have no idea why the problem exists and where to look for the bug.
It would be a great help if someone could point me in the right direction.

P.s in my application class i am initialising pubnub, okhttp,sqlBrite etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using fragments? Sometimes using a fragment stack can lead to blank screens because a fragment holder doesn't inflate the intended fragment.

Another possibility is that you are stuck in a loop that is switching from LoginActivity to HomeActivity and back. I've had both of those problems.

Comment: Could you please add your code/manifest/log results so we can see what you have done?